What's significant about Maetel's kiss in Galaxy Express 999?
I wonder if there is anything significant about Maetel's kiss. Specifically referring to the kiss that she gave to Tetsuro at the end of the movie.
According to this link, it was supposed to symbolize Tetsuro is finally growing up. Is this true? If yes, how so and why?
I remember trying to ask about this and to share this kind of knowledge with someone on the internet, but that someone that I've talked to thinks it is incest. However, I doubt that Leiji Matsumoto is the type of guy to create anime with incest. So I'm assuming there might be some kind of meaning behind it or it might be some kind of symbol.
